# chrome extension only runs when background page is acive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Right now my extension is just supposed to keep track of the user's most frequented sites. However, it only seems to work when my background page is active. For example, if I open my background console or if I make it persistent, it would run without a hitch. However, if my background console is closed or persistent is set to false, it will no longer update the sites time.

Here's my background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    console.log("App Installed");
});

var web_list =[];

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab){


    if(info.status == 'loading'){
        logTime();
        var site = tab.url.match('^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?')[4];

        web_list.push(site);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(){
    logTime();

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        web_list.push(tabs[0].url.match('^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?')[4]); 
//get url of site and then extract host name
    });


});

function logTime(){

    if (web_list.length > 0){
        var url = web_list[web_list.length - 1];

        chrome.storage.sync.get('time', function(data){
            var timeString = data.time;
            var time = new Date(timeString);
            var d = new Date();
            var mins = (d - time)/60000;


            chrome.storage.sync.get(url, function(data){
                var items = data[url];
                if(items){
                    items[0] = items[0] + mins;
                    items[0] = Math.round(items[0]*100)/100;
                    chrome.storage.sync.set({[url]: items});

                }

                else{
                    mins = Math.round(mins*100)/100;
                    items = [mins, false, false, 0, 0, 0];
                    chrome.storage.sync.set({[url]: items});

                }


            });
        });
    }

    var date = new Date();
    var dateString = String(date);
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'time': dateString});
}
```

So for example, after unpacking my chrome extension I visit www.reddit.com in another tab. After reloading reddit, it would say I was on the site for 0.11 minutes or whatever in my popup. However, if I wait a minute, at which point my background script is inactive, and then reload www.reddit.com, the time won't be updated in my popup. However, if persistent is set to true or if the background console is open, it runs perfectly fine and the value is updated to 1.11 minutes.

I'm not sure what to do. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What do you want to avoid by not setting the background page `"persistent"` to true? By the nature of your extension it will be required for it to be persistent.

Comment: I've read in the docs that you should always try to avoid making background pages persistent. I also just want to know why it only works when the background page is persistent.

Comment: There is nothing bad about making it persistent. You are not going to overload anything nor really waste much, if any, resources. It doesn't work when its not persistent because every time it finishes its execution it will be unloaded and thus your data, outside of the `chrome.storage`, lost. In any case you can follow [these docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_migration) if optimum performance of the extension is required.